# Dual Monitors, play movie on one, while typing on another

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have a dual monitor setup for my laptop, running Kubuntu 14.10.  On the laptop I want to be able to load up a text file or Firefox and type at the same time on the second monitor I have a movie playing through mplayer.

What is happening now is that I start up the movie, go to the LCD monitor and the second monitor shows just the desktop.

Comment: What app are you playing the movie in ? should work in mplayer just fine.

Comment: I am using mplayer.  I can try vlc I suppose.

Comment: using vlc the same thing happens.

Comment: What do you mean by "just the desktop" ? are you missing a panel ? is firefox running ?

Comment: The background of my desktop just shows up when I pick another window.

Comment: can you post a screenshot ? Is it just a matter of adding a panel to the other screen or moving an application between screens ?

Comment: What seems to work is if I set the video player to be on All Desktops, I can do what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Press `Super+P` to change projector modes (extended, duplicate, etc) and make sure that System Settings -> Displays shows you an 'extended' setup with both the displays side by side.

Now you can drag any window from one display to another through the common edge, generally the right edge of the laptop display.

Comment: I can't seem to get Super + P to work.  I am using a Playstation USB keyboard so it's probably related to that.  My monitors tho are set to be side by side and are not 'unified'

Comment: Open System Settings -> Displays and check whether the displays are appearing side by side to form an extended display. If so, drag the window from one display to the other.

Comment: That doesn't work either.  What does seem to work though is making the movie window show on all desktops.